# Quick Search Button in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a password dialogue at the start of the application and on pressing the search button , the dialogue disappears and get destroyed , how to recover that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onSearchRequested()` in your password activity and `return false`.  This will prevent the search window from showing up while that activity is active.

Comment: It does work in the activity but it doesn't work in the password dialog .